# Why IntelliJ IDEA removed the force step into button?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, step-into

I was watching a tutorial about debugging in IDEA. When I was trying to try the *force step into* button, I found out it was not there. The shortcut *alt + shift + f7* still works tho.

Why did they remove this button? What is the necessity behind it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Force Step Into*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/stepping-through-the-program.html#force-step-into) is still a feature.

The toolbar button was intentionally removed. Please see [IDEA-299530](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-299530/Remove-force-step-into-from-the-debugger-toolbar) for more information.

> It was decided to remove the force step into from the debugger toolbar because its **usage is very low** and the **red icon is very distracting**. Also, the new toolbar customization (with a toolbar right click) allows to **easily add it back if really needed**.

Please perform the following steps to bring back this action:

- Right-click on the debugger toolbar and select `Customize Toolbar`

[image: debugger toolbar]

- Click on `+ | Add action...| search for "Force Step"`
- Add the needed action. Click OK